# iptables v1.6.1: ! not allowed with multiple source or destination IP addresses

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, docker

I have a docker elastic search cluster running on Ubuntu, since docker writes directly to iptables and by default allows connections from any ip address I am trying to add rules to the iptables to only allow connections from 2x specific ip addresses.

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i ens160 ! -s 192.168.10.10,192.168.11.69 -j DROP
```

When I run this command I get the following error:

```
iptables v1.6.1: ! not allowed with multiple source or destination IP addresses
```

Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split the rule into a `RETURN` (or `ACCEPT` if you prefer) rule and a `DROP` rule:

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i ens160 -j DROP
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i ens160 -s 192.168.10.10,192.168.11.69 -j RETURN
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you very much.

Comment: @piotr-p-karwasz comment helped solve this problem but it didn't work as is.
I had to start with a "-F" to clear it, and use "-A" rather than "-I" for the DROP so it will be in the end.  
  iptables -F DOCKER-USER;
  iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i ens160 -s 192.168.10.10,192.168.11.69 -j RETURN;
  iptables -A DOCKER-USER -i ens160 -j DROP;

Comment: @naviram: thanks, I corrected the order in the answer.